# OpenCV BFMatcher error when matching descriptors from convolution of images in Torch

Tags: opencv, lua, torch

I am doing a brute force matching of descriptors pulled from images using FAST and convoluted through a custom network to provide 64 descriptors of each image.

When doing a comparison I convolute an incoming image and then compare it to a set of descriptors I load from file of an image I have convoluted and saved earlier.

I am getting an OpenCV error: 
`OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (type == src2.type() && src1.cols == src2.cols && (type == CV_32F || type == CV_8U)) in batchDistance, file /home/ec2-user/opencv/modules/core/src/stat.cpp, line 3749`

I try printing the types of tensors with `print(#loaded_descriptors)` and `print(#conv)` and this returns respectively:

```
134
64
[torch.LongStorage of size 2]
```

&

```
134
64
[torch.LongStorage of size 2]
```

----------------------------------------------CODE -------------------------------------------

**CNN Model**

```
local model_params = torch.load(path[i])
net = dofile("../training/models/3x32x32_to_64.lua")(model_params):float())
net:evaluate()
net = net:cuda()
net = cudnn.convert(net, cudnn)
print(net)
```

**Loading descriptors from file**

```
function load_descriptors(csv_path)
  --loop through folder and load descriptors from csv files
  local csv_files = io.popen('ls ' .. csv_path .. '/*.csv')
  for path in csv_files:lines() do
    local keypoints = table.load(path)
    --change table to tensor of, number of features x 64 descriptors
    local tensor_data = torch.CudaTensor(#keypoints,64)
    for i=1, #keypoints, 1 do
      for j=1, 64, 1 do
        tensor_data[i][j] = keypoints[i][j]
      end
    end
  return tensor_data:cuda()
end
```

**Running matching**

```
--Load image and convolute
img = image.load("img.jpg", 3, 'float'):mul(255):cuda()
img = img:view(3,img:size(2)/img:size(3), img:size(3),img:size(3)):transpose(1, 2):contiguous()   
conv = net:forward(img):clone()

--Load descriptors
local loaded_descriptors = load_descriptors(descriptor_path)

--BF Matching
print(#loaded_descriptors)
print(#conv)

matcher = cv.BFMatcher{cv.NORM_L2, False}
local match_ptr = matcher:match{conv, loaded_descriptors}
local res = {}
for i=1, match_ptr.size, 1 do
  table.insert(res, match_ptr.data[i].distance)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that the lua openCV bindings cannot take a `CudaTensor`, you must convert the CudaTensors back into FloatTensor. That conversion can be done by taking the tensor and reassigning it with float:

`conv = conv:float()`

In my script I also had to change the loading of data to:

`local tensor_data = torch.Tensor(#keypoints,64)` (which is default FloatTensor)